# Understanding the Exp map from a moduli of smooth curves

Tags: riemannian-geometry, moduli-spaces, curves

---

**The setup:**

Suppose I'm given a family of class $C^k$ curves $\{f_{z}\}_{z\in Z}$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$ parameter by a finite number of parameters $Z\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.
Let $\mathscr{M}$ be the moduli space obtained from these curves, hence $\mathscr{M}$ may be given the structure of a Riemmanian $\mathscr{C}^k$-manifold, with inner product induced from $\mathbb{R}^d$ (where $dim(\mathscr{M}=d)$.

Therefore for any point $p\in \mathscr{M}$ there exists a well defined $Log_p$ map to $\mathbb{R}^d$.

---

**Question:**
Does there exist an explicit formula (hopefully in terms of $f$) for the $Log_p$ map?

Comment: What's a "curve" in this context? And how is their "moduli space" defined?

Comment: By a curve I mean a map $f_z: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ which  depends on a finite number of parameters in $Z$.  So we can define a map: $F(z,x):\mathbb{R}^{m\times d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, then $Im(F)$ in the space of all $C^k$ curves into $\mathbb{R}^d$ would be the moduli space.